# How to swap between pulseaudio and pipewire without restarting?

Tags: audio, fedora, pulse-audio, pipewire

IIUC, `pipewire` is an audio system service and a newer alternative to `pulseaudio`. It's now the default with Fedora. When first upgrading to Fedora 37 I noticed audio quality was significantly worse, oddly missing low frequency/bass volume. I double checked by switching back to pulseaudio with the following command. The difference was also there when booting to Windows on the same machine.

```
# Use pulseaudio
sudo dnf swap --allowerasing pipewire-pulseaudio pulseaudio
```

To use pipewire again,

```
# Use pipewire
sudo dnf swap --allowerasing pulseaudio pipewire-pulseaudio
```

After running these, a system reboot is needed to stop the old service and start the new one. Is there a faster way to switch between them without rebooting to test audio quality?

(Since upgrading to Fedora 39, I can't tell the difference)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
# Switch to pulseaudio
sudo dnf swap -y --allowerasing pipewire-pulseaudio pulseaudio && { \
 systemctl --user stop pipewire.socket pipewire-pulse ; \
 sleep 1 ; \
 pulseaudio -D ; \
 sleep 1 ; \
 ps -e | grep 'pipe\|pulse' ; }


# Switch to pipewire
sudo dnf swap -y --allowerasing pulseaudio pipewire-pulseaudio && { \
 pkill -x pulseaudio ; \
 sleep 1 ; \
 systemctl --user restart pipewire.socket pipewire-pulse ; \
 sleep 1 ; \
 ps -e | grep 'pipe\|pulse' ; }
```

Each set of commands installs the alternative package, stops the previous service, starts the new one and verifis with a `ps -e`. My guess is `pipewire-pulseaudio` implements some pulseaudio API on top of pipewire, maybe like Xwayland allows running X11 apps on wayland, but with the limitation that it can't exist at the same time as `pulseaudio` so a `dnf swap` is needed.

I found the commands on these forums:

- https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/how-do-i-switch-from-pulseaudio-to-pipewire-and-back/78093
- https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?328748-pipewire-restart
- https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?326248-Just-upgraded-pipewire-and-want-to-reload-it-without-rebooting&p=1848601